# ¿Qué significa el signo de admiración (!) al final de un tipo en Kotlin?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Estoy siguiendo este tutorial para mi app: https://youtu.be/xjsgRe7FTCU?t=381
El enlace los llevará al momento donde tengo el problema.
A mi no me aparece como a él: [image: Así es como le sale a él] A mi no me aparece así.

Así es como tengo esa parte en mi código:

```
val prefs: SharedPreferences.Editor = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
```

En esa parte de código, exactamente esta: ***SharedPreferences.Editor*** a él al final de eso le aparece un signo de admiración y a mi no, si yo se lo pongo no me deja ejecutarlo. Si se lo quito puedo "ejecutarlo" porque si intento ejecutarlo me sale este error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugGoogleServices'
> No matching client found for package name 'com.example.firebasetests'
> * Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
```

No sé si necesiten revisar poco más de mi código pero voy siguiendo el tutorial. Esto es de String.xml:

```
<resources>
<string name="app_name">FireBaseTests</string>
<string name="prefs_file">com.example.firebasetests.PREFERENCE_FILE_KEY</string>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El `SharedPreferences.Editor!` que se ve en el video no es un autocompletado sino una simple ayuda que te da android studio para que sepas de qué tipo es la variable. Lo que realmente está escrito es

```
val prefs = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.prefs_file), Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
```

Si quieres que se vea como en el video sigue este camino `File > Settings > Editor > Inlay Hints > Kotlin > Types` y activa la opción `Show hints for Local variables types`.

Como sabrás, Kotlin es un lenguaje *null-safe* y usa el signo `?` para indicar que el valor de una referencia puede ser `null`. Sin embargo cuando interactua con un leguaje que no tiene *null safety* (en este caso Java), el compilador no tiene forma de saber si una referencia puede ser nula o no y entonces lo representa con el signo `!`. En resumen:

- `T` nunca puede ser `null`
- `T?` puede ser `null`
- `T!` no se definió si puede o no ser `null`

Donde `T` puede ser cualquier tipo, por ejemplo `Int`, `String` o en tu caso `SharedPreferences.Editor`.

Aunque es importante resaltar que la notación `T!` **no es una sintaxis válida** del lenguaje. Solamente la usan el compilador y los IDEs. Este es el motivo por el que obtienes un error al declarar la variable así

```
val prefs: SharedPreferences.Editor!
```

Hoy en día no es muy común ver la notación `T!` porque la gran mayoría de las librerías Java usan las anotaciones `@NonNull` y `@Nullable` que el compilador de Kotlin interpreta correctamente. Lamentablemente, el framework de android no aplica estas anotaciones.

A diferencia de un compilador, tu puedes (y deberías) leer las descripciones de las funciones que usas y así entender que `edit()` no va retornar `null`. Por lo tanto es seguro declarar la variable así

```
val prefs: SharedPreferences.Editor = ...
```

o simplemente

```
val prefs = ...
```

Lo preocupante aquí es que estás introduciendo errores simplemente por copiar código sin tener ninguna idea de lo que hace. Por favor, no hagas eso!

Comment: en realidad aún no entiendo mucho de todas las funciones que hay en el IDK, soy un estudiante y tengo pocos días para entregar mi app, con el tiempo aprenderé pero lo importante que te quería preguntar es: tienes alguna idea del porqué del error? Te lo agradecería mucho

Comment: Entendí que el error solamente aparecía cuando agregabas el  signo `!`. No es así? Si no lo es crea otra pregunta con más detalle porque sólo con la información que diste no sabría decirte cuál es problema.

Comment: Entiendo y gracias, logré encontrar el problema!